# Ionic Cordova app links + camera plugin intent issue in Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-intent, applinks

Ionic 4.11.0

Cordova 8.1.2

Android platform: 8.0.0

I am building an Ionic/Cordova app that makes use of an external authentification mobile app ("Itsme") and I have an issue running it with Android.

From my app, I open the authentification app with an app link. The authentification app then redirects to my app also using an app link, but when it does, my app is actually restarted twice as I can see from the logs in the console.

Furthermore, when I keep using the latest instance of my app that is generated, and I try to use the camera plugin (which is start through an Intent) I can never get the picture back. The return of the plugin switches back to the home Android screen, my app remains in the background, and I don't get any result if I make it come back to the foreground.

I have tested using many different flags in the definition of the app link to my own app (singleTask, singleTop, ...) to no avail.

Using a test native app, I have determined that the flags sent by the authentication app when redirecting to mine with a VIEW intent are the following:

- FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
- FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
- SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_INSET

Any ideas or pointers how to figure out what is exactly going on ?